# Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401 - saving and emailing PDF files from Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have basically non-existent experience in Javascript, but know a little bit of Python so I figured I was up to the task of Frankensteining a couple of pre-made scripts together which I found online. The idea is to look through a list of data, then send PDFs of the appropriate spreadsheet to the desired e-mail address. I have copied my attempt below.

```
// This constant is written in for rows for which an email has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';

function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 16; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1; // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 6); // Fetch the range of cells
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); // Fetch values for each row in the Range.

  const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Get the currently active spreadsheet URL (link)
  const subject = 'Monthly Invoice'; // Subject of email message
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?'.replace('SS_ID', ss.getId()); // Base URL 
  const exportOptions = // Specify PDF export parameters From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    '&size=A4' + // paper size legal / letter / A4
    '&portrait=true' + // orientation, false for landscape
    '&fitw=true&source=labnol' + // fit to page width, false for actual size
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=false' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid='; // the sheet's Id
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[4];
    var message = row[3];
    var emailSent = row[5];

    var client_id = row[0];
    var client_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(client_id);

    if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      const blobs = []; // make an empty array to hold your fetched blobs

      // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
      const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + exportOptions + client_sheet, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ${token}'
        }
      });

      // convert the response to a blob and store in our array
      blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName('${client_sheet}.pdf');

    // If allowed to send emails, send the email with the PDF attachment - 500 emails per day standard
    if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0)
      GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
        attachments: [blobs[i]]
      });
    sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 6).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
    // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
}
    // create new blob that is a zip file containing our blob array
    // const zipBlob = Utilities.zip(blobs).setName(`${ss.getName()}.zip`);
    // optional: save the file to the root folder of Google Drive
    // DriveApp.createFile(zipBlob);
}
```

I'm currently running into this error, however - and honestly I'm lost.

> **Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401**

`Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: <HTML> <HEAD> <TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE> </HEAD> <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"> <H1>Unauthorized</H1> <H2>Error 401</H2> </BODY> </HTML> (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 39, file "send_emails")`

If it helps, line 39 is: 
`const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + exportOptions + client_sheet, {`

Could somebody please assist? Thank you.

Comment: its saying Unauthorized. please check your api credits or try to get full resposnse following error

Comment: @Ravi That's weird, my call for ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() doesn't error at all, so it's definitely getting something. How does muteHttpExceptions work? I can't seem to work that out either

Comment: are you getting token?

Comment: @Ravi I define the token on line 11 and then call it for "Authorization" on 41

Comment: not sure. but dont you would need to pass options as object in fetch method paramater??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the script in your question, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Modification point:

- Unfortunately, in the current stage, the template literal, which was added at ES2015, cannot be used with Google Apps Script. I thought that the reason of your issue might be this.

### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
Authorization: 'Bearer ${token}'
```

#### To:

```
Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
```

And

#### From:

```
blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName('${client_sheet}.pdf');
```

#### To:

```
blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName(client_sheet + '.pdf');
```

### References:

- [Basic JavaScript features](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services#basic_javascript_features)
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Added:

I noticed one more modification point. Please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
var client_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(client_id);
```

#### To:

```
var client_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(client_id).getSheetId();
```

- In order to retrieve `gid`, please use `getSheetId()`.

### Updated: December 19, 2020:

Now, Google Apps Script can use V8 runtime. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime) So [the template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) can be used. But there is an important point. In this case, please use the backtick (grave accent) as follows.

```
Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
```

and

```
blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName(`${client_sheet}.pdf`);
```

Comment: This seems to have changed the error from a 401: Unauthorized to a 400: Bad Request error - but I appreciate the attempt!

Comment: @wonk Thank you for replying. I noticed one more modification point. So I added it. Could you please confirm it? In this case, if `client_id` of `var client_id = row[0];` is not the sheet name, an error occurs. So please be careful this.

Comment: Hold on! I've just changed some of the data I provide, and where it used to fail with this "safe" data too, your changes are now making it send the email! I just have to fix the client_sheet var, but your work is absolutely golden my friend!

Comment: @wonk Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: I've just seen that you've edited your answer to fix my variable before I sent the comment. You're slick, dude. For some reason it's not sending the right sheet still, but you've provided me with a solid foundation - thank you!

Comment: Had the same problem and the first from/to change worked for me

Comment: The last change works for me, have no idea why but thanks a lot

Comment: @Tommy Do Thank you for your comment. When I had answered, the template literals couldn't be used with Google Apps Script yet. So I had proposed such modification. Now, Google Apps Script can use V8 runtime. But even when the template literals can be used, `'${client_sheet}.pdf'` is not correct. In this case, ` is required to be used instead of `'`. Please be careful this.

Comment: none of this worked for me

Comment: @About `none of this worked for me`, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. But, I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question by including the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. Because I cannot imagine your situation from your comment. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I have to apologize for my poor skill. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?