# Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401 - Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have exactly the same problem highlighted in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58503256/request-failed-for-https-docs-google-com-returned-code-401-saving-and-emaili) but none of the suggestions given seems to help and the code I'm testing is pretty much the same as the one described in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76076389/how-do-i-use-urlfetchapp-to-download-a-pdf-of-a-tab-in-a-sheet).

I'm not a GAS expert and this is the code I developed inspired by similar codes on the internet, including a test function written for debugging purposes.

```js
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function testExportGoogleSheet() {
  const ssId = ss.getId();
  const sh = ss.getSheets()[1];
  const fileName = sh.getName();
  const file = exportGoogleSheet(fileName, ssId, sh);

  MailApp.sendEmail('myEmailAddress', 'testSubject', 'testBody',{attachments : file});
}

function exportGoogleSheet(fileName, ssId, sh) {
  let url, urlExt, gid;

  // Base URL
  url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + ssId + '/export';
    
  urlExt = '?format=pdf' +
  // The below parameters are optional...
        '&size=7' +
        '&scale=2' + 
        '&fitw=true' +
        '&fzr=true' +
        '&portrait=false' +
        '&sheetnames=false' +
        '&printtitle=false' +
        '&pagenumbers=false' +
        '&gridlines=true' +
        '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER' +
        '&vertical_alignment=TOP' +
        '&attachment=true';

  gid = '&gid=' + sh.getSheetId();
  
  url += urlExt + gid;

  const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  const params = { method: 'GET', headers: { 'authorization': 'Bearer ' + token } };

  //'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  //'oAuthServiceName': 'spreadsheets',
  //'oAuthUseToken': 'always',

  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(fileName + '.pdf');
  
  return blob;
}

// script error returned at UrlFetchApp.fetch() function call
Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401. Truncated server response:
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
  <H1>Unauthorized</H1>
  <H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>

// appsscript.json manifest file
{
  "timeZone": "myTimeZone",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.currentonly",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"
        ]
}
```

The problem seems to be at the level of the `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` function call.
The code worked for a while, but then I must have changed something into the code and now I can't figure out where the problem is!

I've been googling for days but I can't solve the problem and I'm at a standstill.

Thanks in advance to anyone who wants to help me to solve the problem.

Comment: When I saw your showing script, unfortunately, `ss` is not declared in your function `exportGoogleSheet`. By this, I think that an error occurs at the line of `url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?'.replace('SS_ID', ss.getId());`. But, you say `but the problem is exclusively at the level of the call to the UrlFetchApp.fetch() function.`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script. How about this?

Comment: I created the `testExportGoogleSheet` function just to ask the question here on Stackoverflow. In my code I have a globally defined variable as follows `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`. Try to edit the Question for clarity. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue. For example, in order to correctly replicate your issue, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including your current script for correctly replicating your current issue? By the way, in your script, even when `file` is valid blob, the file cannot be attached. In this case, it is required to be `MailApp.sendEmail('emailAddress', 'Test subject', 'Test body', {attachments: [file]});`. Please be careful about this. By the way, are you restricting the scopes with the manifest file `appsscript.json`?

Comment: By the way, about `I have exactly the same problem highlighted in this link but nothing I read seems to help`, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation.

Comment: I put the actual function I use in the script to send the emails and I've updated the `testExportGoogleSheet` test function acordingly. As told from the beginning I'm sure the problem is at authorization level and not elsewhere.
I also added my `current appscript.json` manifest file. More in general, if I don't have a permission, isn't the development environment asking me to authorize that specific scope I'm requesting? As I told I'm a newbye of GAS developing!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand the detailed method for correctly replicating your current issue. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike did you have time to find some ideas to solve the problem?
In the mean time I've updated the`appsscript.json` file explicitely declaring the script authorization scopes, unfortunately without any success

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to ask the same reply. I think that this is due to my very poor English skill again. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand the detailed method for correctly replicating your current issue. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike If I create the url as per code in my question and paste it into a browser, I get the pdf I'm expecting. But if I just create a testing() function then I get an HTTP 401 in the console when I try to run the function. The error occurs on the URLFetchApp call as already said. I don't think the point is your or mine poor english skills... it is an authorization issue related to a cause I'm not understanding :(

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply and updated question, I guessed the modification point. Please confirm it. If that was not the direct solution to your issue, I apologize, again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your showing manifest file (`appsscript.json`), I guessed that in your situation, the scope might not be enough for using your script. So, please modify `appsscript.json` as follows, and test it again.

```json
{
  "timeZone": "myTimeZone",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly" // <--- Added
}
```

- In this case, I think that the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` can be also used.

Comment: I did some tests and I found an `appsscript.json` configuration that works. Thanks to put me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

After some testing time, I found the `appsscript.json` configuration to fit my script needs.

```js
// appsscript.json manifest file
{
  "timeZone": "myTimeZone",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"
        ]
}
```