# How to retrive the google form name?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm executing a script hooked to a google sheet. The google sheet is the answer sheet of a form. I don't know how to make a reference to the form and get its name.

I tried with the code `const frm = FormApp.getActiveForm().getTitle()`, but it doesn't work (probably because the script I'm executing is hooked to the google sheet and not to the form!)

I tried with the code `const frm = FormApp.openById('myFrmIdString').getTitle()`; the `myFrmIdString` value I used is taken from the URL of the form displayed in the address field of the browser, but it doesn't work.

I googled various sites and couldn't find anything else to successfully retrieve the name of the form referenced to the answer spreadsheet, in turn referenced to  the script I'm excuting.

Thanks in advance to anyone who wants to help me and knows how to solve the problem.

Comment: As per the code above mentioned, I'm interested in the Form title, so I used the `getTitle()` function of the Form object

Comment: Please update your question with the necessary data *(e.g. a dummy Forms file that looks similar to your actual file)*. This will enable people in the community to fully replicate your issue. From there, they can propose a solution that specifically addresses the problem. Please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have a container-bound script of Google Spreadsheet. And, the sheet in the Spreadsheet is linked to Google Form.
- You want to retrieve the title of Google Form from the container-bound script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the container-bound script of Spreadsheet linked to Google Form, and save the script.

```js
function muFunction() {
  const formTitles = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().reduce((o, sheet) => {
    const formUrl = sheet.getFormUrl();
    if (formUrl) {
      o[sheet.getSheetName()] = {
        formTitle: FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl).getTitle(),
        filenameOfForm: DriveApp.getFileById(formUrl.split("/")[5]).getName()
      }
    }
    return o;
  }, {});
  console.log(formTitles);
}
```

- When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

  ```json
  {
    "Sheet1": {"formTitle":"sample form title","filenameOfForm":"sample filename of Google Form"},
    ,
    ,
    ,
  }
  ```
- Unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't u nderstand which you want to retrieve the form title or the filename of Google Form. So, in my sample script, both values are retrieved.

Comment: The script returns the following error msg `Exception: You do not have permission to call FormApp.openByUrl. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms`.
I added that string in the appsscript.json file but the error is still there

Comment: @Jumpy73 About `The script returns the following error msg Exception: You do not have permission to call FormApp.openByUrl. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms. I added that string in the appsscript.json file but the error is still there`, in this case, it is required to replicate your situation. In your situation, how did you run the script? When I run the script with the script editor, unfortunately, the script works without errors. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: @Jumpy73 When I ran the script with the custom function, I confirmed that such the error of `Exception: You do not have permission to call FormApp.openByUrl. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms` occurs. If my test is the same as your actual situation, I have to apologize. Because this is the current specification of the custom function. In that case, please run the script with the script editor instead of the custom function. If I misunderstood your actual situation, I apologize for my poor skill again.

Comment: @Jumpy73 About `As per the code above mentioned, I'm interested in the Form title, so I used the getTitle() function of the Form object`, in this case, I think that `formTitle: FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl).getTitle(),` in my sample script might be your expected value.

Comment: please look at [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/kavyv9q5tlfsm0skpxp8r/muFunction.jpg?rlkey=t3m4n8wgxkyugbst9nd5u5nhl&dl=0). I run all my scripts for testing first by selecting the function name (green arrow) and then by pressing the 'Execute' or the 'Debug' button (red arrow) . I don't think to understand the difference between custom function or script editor modes. Anyway I suppose I'm running my scripts in script editor mode

Comment: @Jumpy73 Thank you for replying. From your reply, please confirm the following flow. 1. You have the permission for accessing the Google Form? 2. Please remove the property of `oauthScopes` from `appsscript.json` and test it again. About `I don't think to understand the difference between custom function or script editor modes.`, you can see about the custom function at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Comment: Again the problem was permissions... modified the `appsscript.json` manifest file as per [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76934071/exception-request-failed-for-https-docs-google-com-returned-code-401-unauth), everything worked

Comment: @Jumpy73 Thank you for replying. About `Again the problem was permissions... modified the appsscript.json manifest file as per link, everything worked`, I'm glad your issue was resolved.